# Which links need canonical tags on three page website

Tags: html, canonical-link

I'm getting issue with **google search console**, saying

> Duplicate without user-selected canonical

So currently my site looks like the following, as you can see it has 6 links in total.

[image: site map]

I have **no canonical tags** on any of them currently, so am wondering which ones need to be in order to solve the problem.

1. Is it just links going back to the homepage (so 3 and 4)?

or

2. Do I not need any here, and the problem must be coming from somewhere else?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Google-bot, as well as other web crawlers, like it when all of your pages have canonical links. So adding these to all of your html heads could potentially solve your problem. However, I am not positive with the limited information given on your circumstance.

```
    <link rel="canonical" href="https://your-website.domain/index.html">
    <link rel="canonical" href="https://your-website.domain/terms.html">
    <link rel="canonical" href="https://your-website.domain/privacy.html">
```

Read this for more information:
https://web.dev/canonical/

Comment: So on all 6 links?

Comment: No, you put them in the <head> of the html pages. (so all 3 pages)

Comment: Gave it a couple days and still getting the `Duplicate without user-selected canonical` with this change.